# How to create context and save parameters in dialogflow webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to create an intent that allow user to send 2 parameters, however, something seems to be wrong that I can't figure. It works fine in dialogflow console

Here is my dialogflow agent inside the console:

[image]

Here is my node js function

```
function test(agent) {

      first = agent.parameters['first'];
      console.log("first");//nothing is returned so I think it does not enter the function 
      second = agent.parameters['second'];

      agent.context.set({
              "name": 'test',
              "lifespan": 2,
              "parameters": {
                "first":first,
                "second":second
              }
      });
      if (first != "") {
        agent.add("the 1st text is: " + first);
      } if (second != "") {
        agent.add("the 2nd text is" + second);
      }
}
```

The result of the chatbot

[image]

I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement I tried replicating the scenario on my end. I tried the same both from Console and using Dialogflow Fulfillment Webhook and in both cases I am getting the expected output.

You can refer to the below mentioned steps  :

- Create one Intent **test**
- Add training phrases to the intent like "first","second" and tag them with **@sys.any**
- In the **Action and Parameter** field define the prompts  like **"What is first" for first and "what is second"  for second.**

[image]

- You need to enable the fulfillment for this intent.

As per the code you have provided, you have used the  **“agent.context.set”**  field.  Since you are not using any **Input and Output Contexts** in your Intent, it is not required to define them in your webhook code.

You can refer to the below Node.js code. I have used the **Node.js 10 client library** for dialogflow.

**Index.js :**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.slot = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
 console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

 function going(agent){
 const value1=agent.parameters[`first1`];
 const value2=agent.parameters[`second2`];
  agent.add(`we received ` +value1+ ` in first field and ` +value2 + ` in second field as per your input`)
 }  

 let intentMap = new Map();
 intentMap.set('test',going);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
 "name" : "slot",
"description": "This is the webhook",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"license": "Apache Version 2.0",
"author": "Google Inc.",
"engines": {
  "node": "10"
},
 "dependencies": {
  "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
  "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
  "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
  "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
  "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"
}
}
```

**output :**
[image]

When you are using a Webhook in Dialogflow, to fetch the parameters from the Intents using webhook, we use the `` agent.parameters[`parameter name`] `` function. The parameter needs to be present in the Dialogflow console or else the Webhook cannot fetch the Parameter values to continue the conversation flow.

In the below screenshot you can check the parameter value  is fetched from the webhook using the `` agent.parameters[`parameter name`] `` function.

[image]

I created a sample website and there I have deployed the Dialogflow Messenger and it is working as expected.

You can refer to the below website screenshot :
[image]

Could you please try using the webhook Node.js code along with the package.json file I have provided in the solution.

If this does not work for you, then please provide your Agent Zip file along with the full Webhook code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the dialogflow messenger demo works fine. However, when using it in my website it still shows the same response, so I did some debugging I found out that if I add the parameters in dialogflow console it does not enter the test function(), and vice-versa if I remove the parameters in dialogflow console, it enters the test function()

Comment: I have removed the set context, and the webhook inside the dialogflow console is enabled, I don't know why it either shows node js function only or dialogflow console only. In addition, I found out that the 1st value is always being updated and the 2nd value is not.

Comment: Hi @Mounir I have updated the answer.